# How WordPress manages its session?

Tags: wordpress, session

I'm curious to know, how WordPress manages its session state.

I have searched for session_start(), but its not there. I'm not sure, if it stores session into DB or any other technique.

Comment: what you trying to achieve?

Comment: Curious, I would say.

Comment: wordpress use `COOKIE` not `session`...